# Can I split crate in multiple files without introducing modules for each file?

Tags: module, namespaces, rust, rust-crates

All examples that I found create a `lib.rs` and then inside that file create `mod foo;`, `mod bar;` for each file `foo.rs`, `bar.rs` and so on.

Basically what I want is to to split my crate into multiple files but without having to introduce lots of modules for every file. Is this not possible with Rust?

Comment: You can have seperate submodules and you `pub use` them in a module you want to export

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to include another source file, it has to be its own module.

However, this does not mean that you must *expose* this fact in your API. For example, let's say you want to put some code in a file called `hidden.rs`:

```
pub fn inside_hidden() {}
```

Now in your `lib.rs` file, you could expose this module:

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]

pub mod hidden;
```

But if your library doesn't require sub-modules, it's probably better to keep the `hidden` module a secret, and instead expose its contents as members of your top-level module:

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]

pub use hidden::inside_hidden;

mod hidden;
```

This way, users won't know you have a `hidden` sub-module. They will see `inside_hidden` as if it were a member of your top-level module.

Comment: Great answer as usual :) Thanks!